# textview multiple fonts and String formatting

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring, custom-font

I have this following string res

```
<string name="description">Your trial ends on
    <annotation font="semi_bold_text">%s</annotation>.
    You will be charged after your trial ends
</string>
```

I am using custom font(Montserrat) in my application. I want to use montserrat-semibold for the expiry date and montserrat-regular for the remaining text.

I will set the expiry date using databinding

```
android:text="@{@string/description(expiry_date)}
```

or by using resources getString() method with varArgs

```
val expiryDate = "Apr 9, 2020"
context.resources.getString(R.string.description, expiryDate)
```

But according to documentation,
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithAnnotations they used annotations for static string alone.

Is there anyway we can combine string formatting with annotations?

Note: We cannot able to use Html.fromHtml() method as they dont support custom fonts as per android official documentation.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource#StylingWithHTML

Comment: Just a suggestion you can use multiple TextViews.

Comment: You can use **SpannableString** to set the multiple fonts in one textview